# Moment, formatting array of dates and getting invalid result

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I am trying to format all the dates in an array. I run the forEach loop and used moment format but in results I am getting invalid result.

```
response =  [
        {
          "type": "blackout",
          "dates": ["2019-12-31T17:52:30.263Z", "2020-11-21T17:52:30.263Z", "2020-11-22T17:52:30:263Z",],
           "description": "Blackout Period"
        }..........................................................................................]



 response.forEach( items => {

     const dates =   moment(items.dates).format('YYYYMMDD');

     console.log(dates, "dkjedjedkjed");
      });
```

Below is stackblitz link.
I implemented one solution but some dates are coming as invalid.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxmkkd

Comment: Because dates is another array. You also need to iterate them.

Comment: I iterated dates in another array, items.date is giving me single date

Comment: `moment()` takes a string, a Date, an object, or a number. An array of strings is none of those. Use `dates = items.dates.map(d => moment(d).format('YYYYMMDD'))`.

Comment: Your code shows `items.dates`. If you'd like help with your actual code, please show your actual code.

Comment: Thats the actual code, I copied response from developer tools and code from my IDE

Comment: Use dates = items.dates.map(d => moment(d).format('YYYYMMDD')). It works but some dates are formatted some are showing invalid

Comment: ngOnInit() {

    this.releaseCalendarService.getProductFeatureListing().subscribe((response =>{
      response.forEach( items => {
     const dates = items.dates.map(d => moment(d).format('YYYYMMDD'));
     console.log(dates, "dkjedjedkjed");
      });
   
    }));

  }

Comment: @HereticMonkey Please find stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxmkkd

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. When I say show your actual code, I mean here on Stack Overflow (you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552)). And when I say actual code, I mean a [mre].

Comment: @HereticMonkey I added stackblitz link. Does it help?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxmkkd

Comment: Not to people who can't access StackBlitz... And not to people who come to this discussion after that stackblitz is removed.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I was not able to make that. But your code works for me. I see, it shows invalid to some date and one of them is "2019-12-02T17:52:30:263Z"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typo? The failing dates use colon (:) instead of decimal point (.) as the milliseconds separator:

"dates": ["2019-12-31T17:52:30.263Z", "2020-11-21T17:52:30.263Z", "2020-11-22T17:52:**30:263Z**",]